# how to properly configure dc.js dimension and group in order to display data element

Tags: dc.js

As I keep adding dimensions to my data set, I encounter an issue of having my bar chart not displaying values of my "account" dimension.
Here is my current fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/yv3nnred/18/

```
 var data = [
            {date: "2015-03-25T12:10:00", resolver: "Group 1",  escalation_pct: 20, bubble: 5,account: "Aon", region: "Americas", x: 1},
            {date: "2015-03-25T12:15:00", resolver: "Group 2",  escalation_pct: 10,  bubble: 5,account: "Boeing", region: "AMEA",  x: 1},
            {date: "2015-03-25T12:25:00", resolver: "Group 3",  escalation_pct: 50, bubble: 10,account: "Zurich", region: "Nordics", x: 1},
            {date: "2015-03-25T12:40:00", resolver: "Group 4",  escalation_pct: 30,  bubble: 1,account: "Aon", region: "Americas", x: 1},
            {date: "2015-03-25T12:35:00", resolver: "Group 5",  escalation_pct: 5, bubble: 10,account: "Boeing", region: "Australia", x: 1},
            {date: "2015-03-25T12:45:00", resolver: "Group 6",  escalation_pct: 13,  bubble: 1,account: "Zurich", region: "UK&I", x: 1}
        ];

var dimAccount = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return + d.account;});

    var accountGroup = dimAccount.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.x});

    var accountChart = dc.barChart("#account-chart");

    accountChart.width(480)
            .height(150)
            .dimension(dimAccount)
            .group(accountGroup)

            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .xAxis().tickFormat();
```

It must be something very basic, I'm just not grasping it yet...

Comment: Just as a clarification - what I'm going for is to have a bar chart, in which every bar represents a separate instance of "account" dimension. The bar height does not matter - just need a way of brush-selecting a range of accounts for filtering. So - "Aon" would be represented by a single bar, "Boeing" would be a single bar, etc...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, going with a row chart was what I needed.
A fully working fiddle is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/yv3nnred/25/

```
var dimAccount = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.account;});

    var accountGroup = dimAccount.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    });

    var accountChart = dc.rowChart("#account-chart");

    accountChart

            .width(500)
            .height(500)
            .dimension(dimAccount)
            .group(accountGroup);
```

Answer (score 1):

A row chart works good. But another option is a selectmenu, because the height of the bar doesnt represent anything you could have a simple dropdown menu with the options.

([dc.selectMenu](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.selectMenu) on 2.1 branch)